# Passing latitude and longitude to lightning:map

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using lightning map to display map with multiple marks in it, It works fine while passing street,state,country as element, But while passing latitude and longitude map is not displaying became blank white page.

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="BoxLocationController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="mapMarkersData" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="mapCenter" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="markersTitle" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="showFooter" type="Boolean" default="true"/>

<!-- init handler which will call 'doInit' fucntion on component load-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>

<!-- render map component only when we have at least 1 record in list.(mapMarkersData) -->   
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.mapMarkersData.length > 0}" >
    <!-- the map component -->
    <lightning:map mapMarkers="{! v.mapMarkersData }"
                   center="{! v.mapCenter }"
                   markersTitle="{! v.markersTitle }"
                   showFooter="{ !v.showFooter }" listView="hidden" />
</aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller working as expected**

```
({
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    
   component.set('v.mapMarkersData',[
        {
            location: {
                City: 'Cap-d\'Ail',
                Country: 'France'
            },

            value: 'France1',
            icon: 'custom:custom26',
            title: 'Cap-d\'Ail'
        },
        {
            location: {
                City: 'Beaulieu-sur-Mer',
                Country: 'France'
            },

            value: 'France2',
            icon: 'custom:custom96',
            title: 'Beaulieu-sur-Mer'
        }
    ]);
}
})
```

**Controller while passing latitude and longitude doesn't work**

```
({
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
   component.set('v.mapMarkersData',[
        {
            location: {
                latitude: '12.912157',
                longitude: '77.606340'
            }
        },
        {
            location: {
                latitude: '12.912157',
                longitude: '80.606340'
            }
        }
    ]);
            
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capitalize Latitude and Longitude

```
location: {
    Latitude: '12.912157',
    Longitude: '77.606340'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs, the

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class LightningMapExample extends LightningElement {
mapMarkers = [{
    location: {
        Latitude: '37.790197',
        Longitude: '-122.396879'
    }
}];
}
```

The JSON array seems to be proper but use the exact params (even in terms of casing)